# Optimizing element searching in a python Heap

Tags: python, heap

I'm looking for an object in a python Heap. Technically, looking for the absence of it, but I assume the logic works similarly.

```
heap = []
heapq.heappush(heap, (10, object))
if object not in [k for v, k in heap]:
    ## code goes here ##
```

However, this check is the longest (most processor-intensive) part of my program at large numbers of elements in the heap.

Can this search be optimized? And if so, how?

Comment: Pushing an object with an attached value, as a tuple. Did I mess something up? EDIT: this was in response to a deleted comment.

Comment: You'll need to give more information on what exactly you are doing, and the full purpose of it, for everyone to know the most optimized solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`heapq` is a binary heap implementation of a priority queue. A binary heap makes a pretty efficient priority queue but, as you've discovered, finding an item requires a sequential search.

If all you need to know is whether an item is in the queue, then your best bet is probably to maintain a dictionary along with the queue. So when you add something to the queue, your code is something like:

```
"""
 I'm not really a python guy, so the code probably has syntax errors.
 But I think you get the idea.
"""
theQueue = [];
queueIndex = {};

queueInsert(item)
    if (item.key in queueIndex)
        // item already in queue. Exit.
    heapq.heappush(theQueue, item);
    queueIndex[item.key] = 1

queuePop()
    result = heapq.heappop();
    del queueIndex[result.key];
    return result;
```

Note that if the item you're putting on the heap is a primitive like a number or a string, then you'd replace `item.key` with `item`.

Also, note that this will not work correctly if you can place duplicates in the queue. You could modify it to allow that, though. You'd just need to maintain the count of items so that you don't remove from the index until the count goes to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with heapq, but here's a compatible implementation that works as long as the heap will not contain multiple copies of the same element.

https://github.com/elplatt/python-priorityq